# Do Bartenders ever make their own inventive drinks for the Christmas holidays in bars?

Tags: drinking, bartending

Does anyone know of any bartenders inventing their own inventive Christmas season drinks that are sold locally in their pub or bar?

I am looking for examples in which the bartender himself is the originator of the drink in question.

If yes, could one explain what the drink is and if it is to symbolizes anything related to the Christmas season.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Do you want to meet such a bartender or just get a new recipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do bartenders try to do this?  Yes.

Do they advertise it as such?  Yes.

Is it truly original - as in nobody, anywhere, anytime, has ever made that drink before?  Maybe.

I used to run a bar, and my bartenders would experiment with these things for various holidays and special events.  Customers want to feel special - they know you're not making the alcoholic equivalent of the Mona Lisa, but having a special drink at your local bar is fun and appealing to them.

Once you get beyond the standard cocktails, bartenders (and bars) try to distinguish themselves with variations and twists (pun intended) to stand out in the marketplace.

For example:

Combine 1 part each of cinnamon-flavored (some rum) and mint-flavored (some vodka) with 2 parts of (some cream liqueur), shake well with ice, serve it in a martini glass that's been rimmed with (some flavored sugar), stick a candy-cane in it, and dust with (some spice).  Call it an "Old Saint Nick" or a "Naughty Rudolph".

Is the Old Saint Nick in XYZ Bar in Birmingham, Alabama, USA the same as the Old Saint Nick in ABC Pub in Birmingham, England?  Probably not.  Does anyone care?  No.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is probably not. Even if they thought it was original, chances are it has been done. Exceptions might include a "twist" on some mixed drink using a local product/ingredient rather than the nationally attainable and normally used ingredient. (Think local brewer's porter/stout to replace Guinness in a Black & Tan)

People can be quite creative, however. Especially if you're trying to clear some aging/less-popular liquors/beers/ingredients off your shelves and out of your inventory. Because it is Christmas, they will probably name it something Christmas-y and say "limited time only." While the same drink 3 months later might have a St Patrick's Day (in the US) theme.

Answer (score 1):

I just heard about [this pop-up bar in DC.](http://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2016/12/20/506178945/christmas-cookie-cocktails-nice-naughty-drinks-for-21-boys-and-girls) It's called Miracle on 7th Street and it's only open during the holiday season. [Here's the menu.](http://www.miracleon7thst.com/menu-2016/)

One of their most interesting, and biggest selling, concoctions is the cookie-dough cocktail (w/ an incredibly terrible name ;)

> "SNOW ANGELS, ICE SKATING, COOKIE DOUGH & SNUGGLES"
>
> Butter-Washed Vodka, Don Ciccio & Figli Coffee Liqueur, Crème de Cacao, Cookie Dough-Infused Frangelico, Milk, Salt, Cookie Dough Bites